# limit of 2 variable functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble solving these 3 limits:

1. $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{5x - y}}{{{x^2} + 2{y^2}}}
   % MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
   % feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
   % hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
   % 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
   % vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
   % fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaCbeaeaaci
   % GGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaacIcacaWG4bGaaiilaiaadMhacaGG
   % PaGaeyOKH4QaaiikaiaaicdacaGGSaGaaGimaiaacMcaaeqaaOWaaS
   % aaaeaacaaI1aGaamiEaiabgkHiTiaadMhaaeaacaWG4bWaaWbaaSqa
   % beaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaaGOmaiaadMhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaik
   % daaaaaaaaa!4BA3!
   $$

If i look at the line $y=mx$ , then I get that the limit approaches infinity for any "$m$" (is that correct?) (also, does that mean that the limit D.N.E?):
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,mx)} \frac{{5 - m}}{{x + 2{m^2}x}} = \infty 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaCbeaeaaci
% GGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaacIcacaWG4bGaaiilaiaadMhacaGG
% PaGaeyOKH4QaaiikaiaaicdacaGGSaGaamyBaiaadIhacaGGPaaabe
% aakmaalaaabaGaaGynaiabgkHiTiaad2gaaeaacaWG4bGaey4kaSIa
% aGOmaiaad2gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccaWG4baaaiabg2da9i
% abg6HiLcaa!4E4E!
$$

2. $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,1)} \frac{{\tan (y - 1){{\sin }^2}(x - y)}}{{{{(x - 1)}^2} + {{(y - 1)}^2}}}
   % MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
   % feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
   % hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
   % 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
   % vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
   % fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaCbeaeaaci
   % GGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaacIcacaWG4bGaaiilaiaadMhacaGG
   % PaGaeyOKH4QaaiikaiaaigdacaGGSaGaaGymaiaacMcaaeqaaOWaaS
   % aaaeaaciGG0bGaaiyyaiaac6gacaGGOaGaamyEaiabgkHiTiaaigda
   % caGGPaGaci4CaiaacMgacaGGUbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaai
   % ikaiaadIhacqGHsislcaWG5bGaaiykaaqaaiaacIcacaWG4bGaeyOe
   % I0IaaGymaiaacMcadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaGGOa
   % GaamyEaiabgkHiTiaaigdacaGGPaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaaa
   % aaa!5C20!
   $$

for this one, i used the lines $y=0$ and $x=0$ to approach the function and for both of them i got that they approach a number over 0, which means that it approaches infinity. But I know that this is not enough to say that the limit is infinity.

3. $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{\tan ({x^3} + {y^3})}}{{\sin ({x^2} + {y^2})}}
   % MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
   % feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
   % hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
   % 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
   % vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
   % fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaCbeaeaaci
   % GGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaacIcacaWG4bGaaiilaiaadMhacaGG
   % PaGaeyOKH4QaaiikaiaaicdacaGGSaGaaGimaiaacMcaaeqaaOWaaS
   % aaaeaaciGG0bGaaiyyaiaac6gacaGGOaGaamiEamaaCaaaleqabaGa
   % aG4maaaakiabgUcaRiaadMhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaiodaaaGccaGGPa
   % aabaGaci4CaiaacMgacaGGUbGaaiikaiaadIhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaa
   % ikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaWG5bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaaiykaa
   % aaaaa!546A!
   $$

For the third one, I was thinking of using substitution, but the statements inside the parentheses aren't the same. Don't really know where to go from here :/

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For the third one, may be writing $$ \frac{{\tan ({x^3} + {y^3})}}{{\sin ({x^2} + {y^2})}}
=({x^3} + {y^3})\frac{{\tan ({x^3} + {y^3})}}{{{x^3} + {y^3}}}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sin\left(x^2+y^2\right)}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$ could help

Comment: thanks! so then i get that the limit  approaches zero :)
would you happen to know if the other 2 are correct?

Comment: @Dana. You are very welcome ! I am not very good with these problems of limits with more than one variable but I accept the risk ! For the first, $\infty$ is correct to me. For the second, I think that the limit is $0$. Move along $x=1$ and remember the limits of $\tan(a)/a$ and $\sin(a)/a$ when $a$ goes to zero.

Comment: @Dana: $\infty$ is not correct for (1); see my answer!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Your reasoning for (2) is incorrect as well, because for a multi-variable function to have a limit it is insufficient to check one straight path. Even checking all straight paths is not enough!

Comment: @user21820. I confessed that I was not in my cup of tea. By the way, for **1** I made a terrible typo ! Please forgive me.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Don't worry! I was just making sure Dana gets the right method. =)

Comment: @user21820. I don't worry. **I just feel stupid**

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to identify the asymptotic behaviour before trying to figure out limits.

**(1)**

You must have done something wrong. $(5x-y)$ can be made to completely vanish along some point sequence towards $(0,0)$, and along that sequence $x^2+2y^2$ is non-zero, so the expression must tend to zero if it has a limit at all. But if we choose another suitable point sequence we can make the expression asymptotically close enough to $\frac{y}{2y^2}$ which does not tend to zero.

**(2)**

You're right that the denominator tending to zero is not enough; it is far from enough. What is important is the whole expression, not one part. Again we can look at the asymptotic behaviour. We know that $\tan(t) \approx t$ and $\sin(t) \approx t$ as $t \to 0$. Let $r=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}$ (the distance to the centre). Then $|\tan(y-1)| = \tan(|y-1|) \le \tan(r)$ and $|\sin(x-y)| = \sin(|x-y|) \le \sin(2r)$. Thus $|\tan(y-1)\sin(x-y)^2| \le \tan(r)\sin(2r)^2 \approx 4r^3$ as $r \to 0$. And $\frac{4r^3}{r^2} \to 0$ as $r \to 0$. Therefore by squeeze theorem you get the limit.

**(3)**

Using the same method as in (2), $\left|\frac{\tan(x^3+y^3)}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}\right| \le \frac{\tan(2r^3)}{\sin(r^2)} \approx 2r \to 0$ as $r \to 0$, and squeeze theorem gives the answer again.

**Note**

Notice that for this kind of limits we need to use squeeze theorem, because we used inequalities.

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer! I may have a stupid question...but why is sin(|x−y|)≤sin(2r)? also for 1 this was my reasoning: lets approach the function from all lines in the form of y=mx : (says i have to many characters so ill make a new comment)

Comment: @Dana: $|x-y| \le |x|+|y|$. As I said in my earlier comment, it is not enough to approach from all angles on straight paths! Even if each of them has the same limit, the function may not have a limit. It's a good exercise to come up with such a function!

Comment: @Dana: If you look at my answer you will realize what went wrong with yours. But please remember that even if nothing goes wrong and all straight paths give the same limit, the limit may not exist.